# connectivitymanager.getActiveNetworkInfo() returning true when Internet is off (Android)?

Tags: android, connectivity

This is the code I am using to determine if the phone is connected to the Internet:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

On an emulator, this is returning true even when I turn my computer's Wi-Fi off. I see a `3G` sign on the topmost bar of the emulator, even when the computer is off the Internet. Is there something wrong with my code, or is this an emulator problem?

Comment: There's an airplane mode in emulator (I guess). Turn it off and the method should return `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `isConnected` instead of `isConnectedOrConnecting` if you want to determine whether the device is connected *at the time of call* to `isOnline`.

Generally, there are many problems/bugs with hardware-features APIs on the emulator, this might be one of them. Your code is fine.

Comment: Can you confirm this code will work on a real device? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to run it on my device.

Comment: It works on my Galaxy S2 as expected: `isOnline` returns true when the device is either on WiFi or the cellular network, and `false` when none of them.